# How to autocomplete only one argument in Cmd2 with argparse

Tags: python, autocomplete, argparse, cmd2

How to autocomplete one argument in argument parser with cmd2.

```py
from cmd2 import Cmd, Cmd2ArgumentParser
import cmd2

numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

class Complete(Cmd):
    parser = Cmd2ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("type", choices=['numbers', 'alphabet'])
    parser.add_argument("value")
    @cmd2.with_argparser(parser)
    def do_list(self, args):
        self.poutput(args.value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Complete()
    app.cmdloop()
```

With this code i can autocomplete the 'type' argument (with choices in add_argument). I want to autocomplete the 'value' argument depending on the 'type' argument. If value is 'numbers', I complete it with the numbers list. if value is 'alphabet', I complete it with the alphabet list.

Is there any way to properly implement this behaviour? or should I implement my own complete_list method?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using the keyword `completer_method` in the `Cmd2ArgumentParser`. It's not yet documented https://github.com/python-cmd2/cmd2/issues/748.

The complete solution

```py
from cmd2 import Cmd, Cmd2ArgumentParser
import cmd2

numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']



class Complete(Cmd):
    def _complete_list_value(self, text, line, begidx, endidx):
        type_ = line.split()[1]
        if type_ == 'numbers':
            x  = [e for e in numbers if e.startswith(text)]
            return [e for e in numbers if e.startswith(text)]
        elif type_ == 'alphabet':
            return [e for e in alphabet if e.startswith(text)]
        else:
            return []

    parser = Cmd2ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("type", choices=['numbers', 'alphabet'])
    parser.add_argument("value", completer_method=_complete_list_value)
    @cmd2.with_argparser(parser)
    def do_list(self, args):
        self.poutput(args.value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Complete()
    app.cmdloop()
```